# Should attributes be passed objects?

Tags: polymer

When I am passing in values to a polymer element attribute, I can pass in an object via Polymer's data binding. However, if I decide to leave "polymer-land" and want to set the attribute to an object, I cannot. Should I be passing in objects into attributes?

If the answer is "no, you should use methods for that"
then a follow-up question would be, "can I call an element's method without being in the Polymer framework?" For example, if I have a Polymer element:

```
<hello></hello>
```

and I want to access a method it has called "world". In Polymer it would be:

```
this.$.hello.world();
```

Is it possible to call this method without being in a Polymer element definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### From inside Polymer

As you pointed out, inside of Polymer, one can use data binding to bind an object to a published property:

```
<polymer-element name="other-el">
  <template>
    <hello-world persons="{{persons}}"></hello-world>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('other-el', {
      created: function() {
        this.persons = [{'name': 'Eric'}, {'name': 'Bob'}];
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

#### From outside Polymer

From outside Polymer, Polymer elements also support serialized arrays/objects for attributes if their [property type is hinted](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#configuring-an-element-via-attributes):

```
<hello-world persons="[{'name': 'Eric'}, {'name': 'Bob'}]"></hello-world>
```

Because `.persons` is a property on the element, you can also set it in JS:

```
document.querySelector('hello-world').persons = [{'name': 'Eric'}, {'name': 'Bob'}];
```

Answer (score 1):

So to answer my own question.

I believe attributes should not be passed objects. If you need to pass an object into an element, use element methods.

To call a method, you can use simple element selection and method call.

```
document.querySelector('hello').world();
```

I thought I had tried this and it didn't work.

-Jay